# Sequence satisfying condition conundrum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the following statement: $(*)$ $\exists$ constants $c \in (0, \infty )$ and $\gamma \in (0,1)$ such that $\|\vec{x}_k - \vec{x}_{k+1}\| \leq c \cdot \gamma^k, 
\ \ \forall \, k \in \mathbb{N}$, I want to prove that 
$\| \vec{x}_p - \vec{x}_q \| \leq c \gamma^p / (1 - \gamma ), 
\ \ \forall \, 1 \leq p \leq q$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

However, if we assume that $q=p+1$ then, by (*) we should have $\|\vec{x}_p - \vec{x}_{q}\| \leq c \cdot \gamma^p$, and not $\| \vec{x}_p - \vec{x}_q \| \leq c \gamma^p / (1 - \gamma )$. So where is the $1/(1-\gamma)$ coming from?

Comment: If $a\leqslant c\gamma^p$ then $a\leqslant c\gamma^p/(1-\gamma)$ hence your objection is moot. In the general case, use the triangular inequality and the upper bound $$\sum_{i=p}^{q-1}c\gamma^i\leqslant c\sum_{i=p}^{\infty}\gamma^i=c\frac{\gamma^p}{1-\gamma}$$

Comment: @Did I didn't pay attention to the fact that $\gamma\in (0, 1)$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following
\begin{align}
\|\vec{x}_p - \vec{x}_{q}\| &=  \|(\vec{x}_p -\vec{x}_{p+1})+(\vec{x}_{p+1}-\vec{x}_{p+2} ) +\cdots +( \vec{x}_{q}   -\vec{x}_{q-1})\|   \\
&\leq \|\vec{x}_p -\vec{x}_{p+1}\|+\|\vec{x}_{p+1}-\vec{x}_{p+2} \|+\cdot  +\| \vec{x}_{q}   -\vec{x}_{q-1}\| \\
&\leq c\sum_{m=p}^{q}\gamma^n \\
&\leq c\sum_{m=p}^{\infty}\gamma^n \\
&=c\frac{\gamma^p}{1-\gamma}
\end{align}